# How to call function template from another function defined earlier?

Tags: c++

I have two function templates A and B. I define A and then B in the same file. Now I would like to call B in A. How can I realize this? Normal function prototype doesn't work in this case. (Please assume you cannot change the order of A and B or split files.)

```
#include <iostream>

template <class Type>
Type A(Type x) {
    return 2 * B(x);
}

template <class Type>
Type B(Type x) {
    return 3 * x;
}

int main() {

    int x = 3;
    std::cout << A(x) << "\n"; //=> ERROR

}
```

ERROR from g++:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Type A(Type) [with Type = int]’:
test.cpp:40:21:   required from here
test.cpp:29:17: error: ‘B’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
     return 2 * B(x);
                ~^~~
test.cpp:33:6: note: ‘template<class Type> Type B(Type)’ declared here, later in the translation unit
 Type B(Type x) {
      ^
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please create a [mcve] to show us, and also include the *full* and *complete* (copy-paste) of the errors (including any possible informational notes).

Comment: `Normal function prototype doesn't work in this case.` Why?

Comment: I just added the full source and the error message.

Comment: Now it's an MCVE, thank you. You did not explain the premise of your question, though, i.e. _"Normal function prototype doesn't work in this case"_, which is false. Ah well, makes for an easy answer ;)

Comment: @DeiDei Sorry, I misunderstood the C++ grammar. Actually it worked as you implied.

Comment: Peace in our times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by prototype you mean declaration, it certainly does work in this case!

You can declare a function template just fine:

```
#include <iostream>

// Non-defining declaration B
template <class Type>
Type B(Type x);

// Defining declaration A
template <class Type>
Type A(Type x) {
    return 2 * B(x);
}

// Defining declaration B
template <class Type>
Type B(Type x) {
    return 3 * x;
}

int main() {
    int x = 3;
    std::cout << A(x) << "\n"; //=> NO ERROR
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a82f66d3024cfe62))

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I wanted. I misunderstood the way of writing "non-defining declaration" so I said "Normal function prototype doesn't work in this case.".